# how to access token of REST Api in magento 1.9.3.1?

Tags: magento-1.9, token

Hi i searched the around google about this, but nothing find. 
can anyone help me to access the token from rest api in magento.

I tried this code in a php file on root and getting blank screen(no output).

```
<?php
/**
 * Example of retrieving the products list using Admin account via Magento REST API. OAuth authorization is used
 * Preconditions:
 * 1. Install php oauth extension
 * 2. If you were authorized as a Customer before this step, clear browser cookies for 'yourhost'
 * 3. Create at least one product in Magento
 * 4. Configure resource permissions for Admin REST user for retrieving all product data for Admin
 * 5. Create a Consumer
 */
// $callbackUrl is a path to your file with OAuth authentication example for the Admin user
$callbackUrl = "http://192.168.0.78/pooja/testmagento/";
$temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl = "http://192.168.0.78/pooja/testmagento/oauth/initiate?oauth_callback=" . urlencode($callbackUrl);
$adminAuthorizationUrl = 'http://192.168.0.78/pooja/testmagento/admin/oAuth_authorize';
$accessTokenRequestUrl = 'http://192.168.0.78/pooja/testmagento/oauth/token';
$apiUrl = 'http://192.168.0.78/pooja/testmagento/api/rest';
$consumerKey = '5c795558a40557839702605ddf3f6a90';
$consumerSecret = '56a0e944528b995baab7bab4b1a9c53b';

session_start();

if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && isset($_SESSION['state']) && $_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
    $_SESSION['state'] = 0;
}
try {
    $authType = ($_SESSION['state'] == 2) ? OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION : OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI;
    $oauthClient = new OAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, $authType);
    $oauthClient->enableDebug();

    if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && !$_SESSION['state']) {
        $requestToken = $oauthClient->getRequestToken($temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl);
        echo $_SESSION['secret'] = $requestToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        $_SESSION['state'] = 1;
        header('Location: ' . $adminAuthorizationUrl . '?oauth_token=' . $requestToken['oauth_token']);
        exit;
    } else if ($_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
        $oauthClient->setToken($_GET['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
        $accessToken = $oauthClient->getAccessToken($accessTokenRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['state'] = 2;
        $_SESSION['token'] = $accessToken['oauth_token'];
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $accessToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        header('Location: ' . $callbackUrl);
        exit;
    } else {
        echo "a= ".$oauthClient->setToken($_SESSION['token'], $_SESSION['secret']);

        $resourceUrl = "$apiUrl/products";
        $oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl, array(), 'GET', array('Content-Type' => 'application/json'));
        $productsList = json_decode($oauthClient->getLastResponse());
        print_r($productsList);
    }
} catch (OAuthException $e) {
    print_r($e->getMessage());
    echo "<br/>";
    print_r($e->lastResponse);
}
```

Thanks.
Pooja

Answer (score 1):

You cannot find the token and token secret from Magento backend. You need to query these from the database directly.

First login to Magento backend and go to System->Web Services->REST - Oauth Consumers. Take a note of the oauth consumer you need the keys for. You can also find consumer_key and consumer_secret from there if you click on that consumer's row. However it's easy to find the keys from DB also:

The consumers and secrets are stored in DB table oauth_consumer. Find the necessary user by column "name" from there and copy the columns "key" and "secret". These are "consumer_key" and "consumer_secret". Take a note of entity_id in oauth_consumer table.

Then look at DB table oauth_token. Find a record by consumer_id and copy columns "token" and "secret".

Now you have all the 4 keys that are necessary to make a fully authenticated Oauth request towards this Magento instance.

Reference:
This is a duplicate - [Rest api, tokens?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/28797/rest-api-tokens)

Comment: is there any way to get the token key in php file.

Comment: "Then look at DB table oauth_token. Find a record by consumer_id and copy columns "token" and "secret"."

I have no token key in my database.

Answer (score 1):

**PHP Examples** from [dev doc magento-1](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html#RESTAPIIntroduction-PHPExamples)

Create a simple product as an Admin user with OAuth authentication

```
<?php
/**
* Example of simple product POST using Admin account via Magento REST API. OAuth authorization is used
*/
$callbackUrl = "http://yourhost/oauth_admin.php";
$temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl = "http://magentohost/oauth/initiate?oauth_callback=" . urlencode($callbackUrl);
$adminAuthorizationUrl = 'http://magentohost/admin/oauth_authorize';
$accessTokenRequestUrl = 'http://magentohost/oauth/token';
$apiUrl = 'http://magentohost/api/rest';
$consumerKey = 'yourconsumerkey';
$consumerSecret = 'yourconsumersecret';

session_start();
if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && isset($_SESSION['state']) && $_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
    $_SESSION['state'] = 0;
}
try {
    $authType = ($_SESSION['state'] == 2) ? OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION : OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI;
    $oauthClient = new OAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, $authType);
    $oauthClient->enableDebug();

    if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && !$_SESSION['state']) {
        $requestToken = $oauthClient->getRequestToken($temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $requestToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        $_SESSION['state'] = 1;
        header('Location: ' . $adminAuthorizationUrl . '?oauth_token=' . $requestToken['oauth_token']);
        exit;
    } else if ($_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
        $oauthClient->setToken($_GET['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
        $accessToken = $oauthClient->getAccessToken($accessTokenRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['state'] = 2;
        $_SESSION['token'] = $accessToken['oauth_token'];
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $accessToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        header('Location: ' . $callbackUrl);
        exit;
    } else {
        $oauthClient->setToken($_SESSION['token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
        $resourceUrl = "$apiUrl/products";
        $productData = json_encode(array(
            'type_id'           => 'simple',
            'attribute_set_id'  => 4,
            'sku'               => 'simple' . uniqid(),
            'weight'            => 1,
            'status'            => 1,
            'visibility'        => 4,
            'name'              => 'Simple Product',
            'description'       => 'Simple Description',
            'short_description' => 'Simple Short Description',
            'price'             => 99.95,
            'tax_class_id'      => 0,
        ));
        $headers = array('Content-Type' => 'application/json');
        $oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl, $productData, OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST, $headers);
        print_r($oauthClient->getLastResponseInfo());
    }
} catch (OAuthException $e) {
    print_r($e);
}
```

Comment: where is "oauth_admin.php" ?

Comment: i used this code, but getting blank screen.

Comment: It's a PHP example code from dev doc magento-1. You must adapt it for your way.